# Contraction of tensors in chart (xCoba)

Tags: physics, xact

I have to do some calculations on modified gravity in xAct. The question is how to construct tensors, made of other tensors with contraction in particular chart. Without chart it can be done with `IndexSet` function, but it doesn't work, when chart is specified. For example, here my trial of calculation for FRW metric:

```
<< xAct`xTensor`
<< xAct`xTras`
<< xAct`xCoba`

DefManifold[M, 4, {a,b,c,d,e,f,h,i,j,k,l,m,n}]

DefChart[ch, M, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], x[], y[], z[]}, ChartColor -> Green]

DefScalarFunction[a]

MatrixForm[ met = DiagonalMatrix[{1, -a[t[]]^2, -a[t[]]^2, -a[t[]]^2}], {-ch, -ch}]

g = CTensor[met, {-ch, -ch}]

SetCMetric[g, -ch]

CD = CovDOfMetric[g]

MetricCompute[g, ch, All]

IndexSet[QQ, g[a, b] (Christoffel[CD,PDch][c, d, -b] Christoffel[CD,PDch][d, -a, -c] - delta[c, -e] Christoffel[CD,PDch][e, -d, -c] Christoffel[CD,PDch][d, -a, -b])]
```

And here I get an error:

`MetricsOfVBundle: There is no metric in TM.`

`Throw: Uncaught Throw[Null] returned to top level.`

All I want is just calculate the following object in FRW chart:

$g^{\nu \beta}(\Gamma{^\rho_{\gamma \beta}}\Gamma{^\gamma_{\nu \rho}} - \Gamma{^\rho_{\gamma \rho}}\Gamma{^\gamma_{\nu \beta}})$

So, how can I do it?

Comment: There are three small issues in your code: 1) The symbol a cannot be used as a scalar function because it was already used as an index. I'd suggest to use A for the scalar function. 2) The correct SetCMetric command is SetCMetric[g, ch, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}]. Note that the chart is given as ch, not as -ch. We also need to specify the signature manually because xCoba can not compute it in this case. And 3) The index d in the first Christoffel should be -d. Once you fix those three things, it should work.

Comment: Note also that you don't really need IndexSet in the last assignment, because the LHS of the assignment does not have indices. IndexSet[lhs[inds], rhs] is a form of Set that makes sure that the indices on the LHS will not interfere with the possible indices on the RHS.

Comment: Thanks you a lot! My original code actually doesn't have the issue with indices, I use greek letters in Wolfram. I've replaced them here, because StackExchange engine doesn't show expressions like ```\[alpha]``` correctly. 

The real problem was with definition of metric. I followed your advice and it works! The answer is  $6\dot{a}^2/a^2$, btw :)